# Mobile operator billing

Tags: windows, mobile, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

Do I need to do something in the code to provide this capability (mobile billing)? Or Microsoft does it himself?
For more information see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215902%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to do anything special, it is transparent for the developers, you just make your app paid or use in-app purchases and Microsoft takes care of the rest.